# Spock bug? callRealMethod() on stub does not throw expected exception

Tags: spock, stub, spy

Extract from class `CUT` under test:

```java
def compileOutputLines( TopDocs topDocs ) {
    println "gubbins"
}
```

Test code:

```java
def "my feature"(){
    given:
    CUT stubCut = Stub( CUT ){
        compileOutputLines(_) >> { TopDocs mockTD -> 
            // NB no Exception is thrown
            // try {
            println "babbles"
            callRealMethod()
            println "bubbles"
            // }catch( Exception e ) {
            //  println "exception $e"
            // }
        }
    }
    CUT spyCut = Spy( CUT ){
        compileOutputLines(_) >> { TopDocs mockTD ->
            println "babbles 2"
            callRealMethod()
            println "bubbles 2"
        }
    }

    when:
    stubCut.compileOutputLines( Mock( TopDocs ))
    spyCut.compileOutputLines( Mock( TopDocs ))

    then:
    true
}
```

Output to `stdout`:

> babbles
>  
>   bubbles
>  
>   babbles 2
>  
>   gubbins
>  
>   bubbles 2

I tried to find a link online to the full Spock Framework Javadoc... but I couldn't find it... the "non-framework" Javadoc is [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.1-rc-4/index.html), but you won't find the method `callRealMethod` in the index.

From the Javadoc API I have generated locally from the source, I can indeed find this method: it is a method of `org.spockframework.mock.IMockInvocation`.  It says:

> java.lang.Object callRealMethod()
>
> Delegates this method invocation to the real object underlying this
>   mock object, including any method arguments. If this mock object has
>   no underlying real object, a CannotInvokeRealMethodException is
>   thrown.
>
> Returns:
>       the return value of the method to which this invocation was delegated

My understanding (such as it is) is that a Stub should cause this `Exception` to be thrown.  But it doesn't appear to be.  Any comment from a passing expert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Preface

This is an interesting question. In theory my answer would be:

> `callRealMethod()` is only available for spies, not for mocks or stubs. It is also only mentioned in the chapter about spies, did you notice?
>
> Think about it: A spy wraps a real object, so there you have a reference to a real method you can call. The same is not true for mocks and stubs which are just no-op subclasses. If you could call a real method for a stub, it would be a spy.

#### The puzzle

In reality I am seeing a different, even weirder behaviour from yours in my own test with Spock 1.1 (Groovy 2.4): No matter if I use a mock, stub or spy, `callRealMethod()` **always** calls the real method. This is really a surprise. So, yes, the behaviour is different from what I would have expected. Looking through the interface implementation's source code while debugging, I also cannot see any checks for the type of mock object (is it a spy or not?). The real method is just identified and called.

#### The solution

Looking at class [`DynamicProxyMockInterceptorAdapter`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/spock-1.1/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/DynamicProxyMockInterceptorAdapter.java) I found the explanation for this behaviour: The exception mentioned in the `IMockInvocation` Javadoc is only thrown when trying to call the real method for an interface type mock, never for mocks or class type objects:

```java
public Object invoke(Object target, Method method, Object[] arguments) throws Throwable {
  IResponseGenerator realMethodInvoker = (ReflectionUtil.isDefault(method) || ReflectionUtil.isObjectMethod(method))
    ? new DefaultMethodInvoker(target, method, arguments)
    : new FailingRealMethodInvoker("Cannot invoke real method '" + method.getName() + "' on interface based mock object");
  return interceptor.intercept(target, method, arguments, realMethodInvoker);
}
```

So the sentence *"if this mock object has no underlying real object, a (...)Exception is thrown"* is in essence correct, but ambiguous because it does not explain what "underlying real object" means. Your assumption was just wrong, so was mine. Lesson learned for both of us.

Now when would you see the described behaviour?

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public interface MyInterface {
  void doSomething();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.spockframework.mock.CannotInvokeRealMethodException
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyInterfaceTest extends Specification {
  def "Try to call real method on interface mock"() {
    given:
    MyInterface myInterface = Mock() {
      doSomething() >> { callRealMethod() }
    }
    when:
    myInterface.doSomething()
    then:
    thrown(CannotInvokeRealMethodException)
  }

  def "Try to call real method on interface stub"() {
    given:
    MyInterface myInterface = Stub() {
      doSomething() >> { callRealMethod() }
    }
    when:
    myInterface.doSomething()
    then:
    thrown(CannotInvokeRealMethodException)
  }

  def "Try to call real method on interface spy"() {
    given:
    MyInterface myInterface = Spy() {
      doSomething() >> { callRealMethod() }
    }
    when:
    myInterface.doSomething()
    then:
    thrown(CannotInvokeRealMethodException)
  }
}
```

---

**Update:** I have just created [issue #830](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/830) requesting improvements in Spock's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To clarify: the whole point is that I realised the method is only for Spies... with a Mock or Stub it should, according to the quoted documentation, throw this Exception. I'm quite confused about your Mocks/Stubs running the real method! I'm on Groovy 2.6 ... could that explain that weirdness?  Thanks for creating that issue... but wouldn't it also be good if Spock *did* in fact throw an Exception when trying to use this method with a Mock/Stub?

Comment: NB as a more general thing I've sometimes been surprised, over the past couple of months as I've been getting to grips with Spock, that it seems quite "unforgiving" to newbs, in the sense that you can put some pretty much "illegal" code in `given`, `when` or `then` ... and Spock stays silent on the matter.  No doubt implementing more checking would have a performance cost... but it'd be great if there could be a special "code-policing" mode which you could choose to run Spock in when puzzled by the results you're getting.

Comment: Having used Spock for a while as well, even though I am just an Agile Coach putting hands on code only when tutoring devs or when bored and trying to unblock the team while trying to find a bug or solve a test issue, I found Spock's behaviour quite easy to debug in most cases. So we have different experience, as it seems. BTW, this issue is a rather academic example IMO because `callRealMethod()` should not be used from anything but spies and having to use spies at all is a smell in many cases. Usually one should rather refactor than use spies.

Comment: I just noticed your first comment, only saw the second one before. As to your question: _"Wouldn't it also be good if Spock did in fact throw an Exception when trying to use this method with a mock/stub?"_ Yes, I think it should so as to keep testers from playing "dirty" and writing counter-intuitive (thus incomprehensible) test code just because they can. But I can live with the current behaviour if it gets properly documented. Besides, would you mind accepting the answer? Or are there any open questions?

Comment: Ah, yes, the old "don't use Spy" thing. ... the problem is that I'm basically trying to teach myself TDD by my own bootstraps. By "TDD" I currently understand: *"don't write a line of app code before you have a failing test"*: in other words I'm not just writing tests which test interaction between classes, and frankly I find it impossible to "do without" running actual methods of real objects... so I use Spy quite a lot. I've done "TDD 101" tutorials many times ... but really need some book to teach me how the professionals apply TDD to the development of real-world projects!

Comment: Sorry that my lecturing comment annoyed you. Sorry, that's me and I want to help. BTW, I was not talking about TDD, even though I think that it is a good practice. Whether you write your test right before the next baby step or right after you changed/added something in/to a module is not as important as testability itself. It is not so difficult to achieve either. If you can **inject dependencies** into objects instead of creating or requesting them from inside, you already are a big step closer, because then you can inject mocks and easily test your code. It is not rocket science.

Comment: No... no annoyance at all! I'm sure I'll understand more one day!